# Filezilla копирует не все без ошибок

Tags: ubuntu, хостинг

Использую *ftp* клиент *Filezilla* , но есть проблема.

Знаю, что у себя в папке 1119 файлов, но *Filezilla* копирует на хостинг 1080. Проблема в том, что она даже не выдает ошибки, а когда заходишь во вкладку (не скопировано), то там 0 файлов.

Была ли у кого еще такая проблема?

*Ubuntu 16.04*

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема, когда в папке были скрытые файлы и Filezilla их не видела.